# How to make the user rate the content

Tags: user-behavior, ratings

In the website/app users will have access to content from experts such as video tutorials and so on. I need them to rate every content they use/watch but i'm afraid they'll leave because of it.

Any idea in order to make the rating less painfull ? Gamification ? Likert scale with Smileys ?

Here is what it looks like for now.

[image: Rating]

Comment: Why do you think that? Users love to rate everything they can

Comment: You can't *make* them do anything. Not without resorting to dark patterns or something. You should be looking to *encourage* them to do it instead. Make it worth their while. Like with eBay - you don't *have* to rate your sellers, but if you do it helps increase your own reputation. Same with this site - Stack Exchange gives you perks for reviewing, upvoting, etc. You don't *have* to do any of that, but you get a bigger number next to your name if you do. And people love making their numbers bigger.

Comment: In my case when they rate it will also make their profile more accurate which will allow them to have more personalized content. But I like the reputation idea, it might encourage them even more

Comment: Curious as to how you would deliver "_more personalized content_" after a user completes the ratings above... if they don't rate "_Resource quality_" very high, will you now switch to higher-quality resources for that user, and leave other users with "moderate-quality" resources because they are "happy enough"?

Comment: If they rate the ressource as low quality the expert who posted it will be notified so he/she can improve the ressource itself. Also the idea is not to switch to high quality resource for people unhappy. The idea is to tend to the best fit between a specific user and specific ressources

Answer (score 1):

You can just make that part optional if you are afraid that there's too many steps for them to do it. They would then be able to rate only the parts that matter to them and/or leave a comment. However, may make your data harder to analyze in the future and more worth it if you do force users.

Since working memory is involved the rule of thumb is 5-9 max things to do-although there are plenty of exceptions to this (https://uxmyths.com/post/931925744/myth-23-choices-should-always-be-limited-to-seven ). But if you chunk those things into categories it seems like less things to do- your star ratings are altogether so the user may feel like it is really one step instead of 3 separate ratings because they are physically close together and don't require too much thinking to get through.

Read the book called Nudge: Improving Decisions About Health, Wealth, and Happiness by Richard Thaler to get a really great understanding of how to create what he refers to as "choice architecture".

Comment: Second time i hear about this book, i'll definitely get it. I can't really make the rating part optional because we need that feedback data, that's why I'm trying to find a way to make the rating more fun.
I'll try to present the rating in order that it look like one single step !

Comment: just coming back to this but another idea could be to actually make more steps instead of one big step. So it presents it in like a wizard like format, rate this:, now this:, now this:, now you're done". At the end of the day i think what you have is fine, you would need to split test to see the differences on how they perform with your particular audience.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe I could allow  users to skip the rating and come back to it later.
It means that somewhere in the app the user will have a list of everything he rated and what's left to rate.

( PS : just started the book, I have a better idea of what "choice architecture" means )

Comment: Here's an idea. If you incentivize them it will ensure they do it. Like another way to think about this is from gaming, called "win states" and "desired actions" . Your desired action is to get the user to rate but they currently don't "win" anything from doing that, so if you can figure out a way to give them a small reward such as an exclusive video tutorial for free then it will get ppl to do it. Involves more technology but if you see the results not coming in, that's something you can try. The audience will give you the answer eventually.

Answer (score 1):

This one is simple: don't make it mandatory to rate a video, make it optional. Not everything one sees or uses makes an impression either way.

Comment: I need the feedback data, if one doesn't rate it would be because he didn't see the whole content

Comment: _You_ needing the data isn't enough to justify forcing users to rate it -- many _will_ leave if you try to enforce that. And do you truly _need_ the data? If it's to "improve user experience" then you _don't_ need it... having it _may_ make a user's experience better, but there's no guarantee, and they may not care (or not believe you... too many websites use the umbrella "_to improve your experience on this site_" when they really mean "_to market your data to death_").

Comment: The global principle of the website is that user will profile themselves, experts will profile resources. And when users use resources, their rating will help improve the resource's profile and will also adjust their own profile. That's why I truly need the data : because this platform is all about data.
Maybe you are right and it shouldn't be mandatory but the more we get feedback the more we will tend to a good fit between users and resources